# Further deriving the weak field limit in general relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors, general-relativity

> Consider the motion of a slow moving particle with worldline $x^a = x^a(t)$. We have
>
> $$\frac{dx^0}{dt}=1, \frac{dx^1}{dt}=u_1,\frac{dx^2}{dt}=u_2,\frac{dx^3}{dt}=u_3$$
>
> where $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ is the velocity in the inertial coordinates on Minkowski space. In particular we have $\gamma(u) \sim 1$ and so we can identify the coordinate time $t$ with the proper time $\tau$ along the worldline, and so approximate the four-velocty by
>
> $$(V^a)=(1,u_1,u_2,u_3)$$
>
> The geodesic equation is
>
> $$\frac{d^2x^a}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma_{bc}^a\frac{dx^b}{d\tau}\frac{dx^c}{d\tau}=0$$
>
> Because we ignore products of the spatial components of the four-velocity with the Christoffel symbols, this is approximated by
>
> $$\frac{d^2x^a}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma_{00}^a=0$$
>
> We also ignore terms involving time $(x^0)$ derivatives of the metric components.

1) Where has the $\gamma(u) \sim 1$ come from?

2) a) are we ignoring products due to being slow moving?

b) I still cant see how the last equation has been derived

3) We do we only ignore components of the time derivative? Why not the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answner:

For your first question, here a hint: consider that $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}$
where $\beta = v/c$, approximate $\gamma$ when $\ v << c$  (Slow moving particle).

for the second and third question's:

yes, $\frac{dx^i}{d\tau}\frac{dx^j}{d\tau}=\gamma^2 u^i u^j$, 
$\gamma^2 \approx 1$, then $\frac{dx^i}{d\tau}\frac{dx^j}{d\tau}=u^i u^j$, if the particle's velocity is sufficiently small, the product of these two vectors is negligible, then we consider only the "time component" i.e. $\Gamma_{00}^a\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}$, but $\frac{dx^0}{dt}=1$, then $\frac{d^2x^a}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma_{00}^a=0$.

about the third question, when the spacetime is static i.e. time-independent, all time-derivatives of the metric vanishes.

*Obs: the $ \gamma$ factor that i mentioned is called Lorentz factor, here a [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) about this.